# Changing the path a property is bound to at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a ComboBox with a list of objects bound to it.
Currently i have the items templated so they show only the property Class.Name. so the ComboBox is full of Class.Name
However i am required to give the user the option to display the property Class.Description instead. If it were just that easy i would be fine, but they want the option to switch back and forth between them at runtime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this directly in WPF.

I would alter the business objects to include an additional Readonly property, something like, DisplayTextProperty

```
Public ReadOnly Property DisplayTextProperty()
    Get
        If ShowDescription Then
            Return Description
        Else
            Return Name
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

I have done this in a few places now and it works great.

Comment: I was hoping there was some way of dynamically binding it, but hey, this works a charm! thanks mate